# Do barcode scanners work on ubuntu?

Tags: usb, compatibility

I want to buy a barcode scanner to read labels from our products.
I don't know if it will work on ubuntu.
I have the option to get a CiperLAB 1070.

Will it work if plugged in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost all barcode scanners will work (serial port connectors need a little extra config but they're pretty rare now).  They'll work just like a second keyboard (for USB connections) or a regular keyboard (for wedge types).  Most scanners are preconfigured to emulate a keyboard but can be reconfigured for POS applications.
We use Datalogic scanners with Ubuntu (both USB and Wedge types) and they work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. I am glad to know this hardware will work.
I refuse to buy hardware that doesn't work in linux.